# Does Artillery support html methods other that GET and POST?

Tags: html, load-testing, artillery

I'm trying to develop scenarios for load testing an application with Artillery. The application in question uses the GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE html methods, but all of the available documentation I've been able to find only discusses the get: and post: keywords (under scenarios: - flow:) which I assume would use the GET and POST methods. At least two sources I've found, including [one at artillery.io](https://artillery.io/docs/guides/guides/http-reference.html), imply that PUT, PATCH, and DELETE are supported, but then provide no information on how to specify the http method on an http request. Can someone advise how to specify PUT and DELETE requests in an Artillery scenario?

(By the way, there are at least 10 other html methods besides the 5 mentioned here.)

Answer (score 0):

PUT and DELETE will follow similar patterns as GET / POST

```
config:
  target: "https://example.com"
  phases:
    - duration: 10
      arrivalRate: 1
  scenarios:
    - flow:
        - delete:
           url: "/users/12345"
        - put:
           url: "/users/12345"
           json:
             firstName: "hello world"
             lastName: "Huh!"
```

Comment: https://artillery.io/docs/guides/guides/http-reference.html#GET-POST-PUT-PATCH-DELETE-requests